# SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_datastore/server/classes/datastore.lua:34: attempt to index a nil value (local 'obj')

Tags: mysql, sql, lua, fivem

I have a problem with the esx_datastore in a FiveM server. The problem is that whenerver I try to open a storage (e.g. the police storage) it drops this error:

[image: 1]

in the txAdmin console. I guess the problem is in the database but im not sure.
These are the codes on the mentioned locations:

[script:esx_policejob] > ref (@esx_policejob/server/main.lua:251)
[image: 2]

[script:esx_policejob] > handler (@esx_datastore/server/main.lua:66)
[image: 3]

[script:esx_policejob] > TriggerServerCallback (@es_extended/server/functions.lua:162)
[image: 4]

[script:esx_policejob] > handler (@es_extended/server/common.lua:122)
[image: 5]

My database:

**datastore** :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `datastore`
--

CREATE TABLE `datastore` (
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shared` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `datastore`
--

INSERT INTO `datastore` (`name`, `label`, `shared`) VALUES
('society_ambulance', 'Ambulance', 0),
('society_police', 'Police', 0);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `datastore`
--
ALTER TABLE `datastore`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`name`);
COMMIT;
```

**datastore_data** :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `datastore_data`
--

CREATE TABLE `datastore_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `datastore_data`
--

INSERT INTO `datastore_data` (`id`, `name`, `owner`, `data`) VALUES
(1, 'society_ambulance', NULL, '\'{}\''),
(2, 'society_police', NULL, '\'{}\''),
(3, 'society_ambulance', '299dddd700c9c058e069e2fa0bad18427efaf4d4', '{}'),
(4, 'society_police', '299dddd700c9c058e069e2fa0bad18427efaf4d4', '{}');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `datastore_data`
--
ALTER TABLE `datastore_data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `index_datastore_data_name_owner` (`name`,`owner`),
  ADD KEY `index_datastore_data_name` (`name`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `datastore_data`
--
ALTER TABLE `datastore_data`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
COMMIT;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72027281/edit). Thanks in advance.